# Formula for the distance from a point to a straight line in $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I [quote](http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/cos702/lecture8.pdf):

> [W]e note that the distance $D$ from a point $\mathbf{p}$ to a line
>   with vector equation $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}_0 + t\mathbf{v}$, where
>   $\mathbf{v}$ is a unit vector, is given by $$ D = || (\mathbf{p} -
> \mathbf{r}_0) - \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^{\top}(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{r}_0)
> ||_2 $$

Where does the above formula come from?

If I do the calculations I get a different expression.

The point on the line that is closest to $\mathbf{p}$ is some point
$\mathbf{g}=\mathbf{r}_0 + t\mathbf{v}$ such that $(\mathbf{g}-\mathbf{p})
\perp \mathbf{v}$.  Therefore

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{v}^{\top} (\mathbf{r}_0 + t\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{p}) &= 0 \\
\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{r}_0 + t\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{p} &= 0 \\
t &= \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{r}_0
\end{align}
$$
and then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{g} &= \mathbf{r}_0 + t\mathbf{v} \\
\mathbf{g} &= \mathbf{r}_0 + (\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{r}_0)\mathbf{v}
\end{align}
$$
so the distance $D$ is
$$
D = || \mathbf{g} - \mathbf{p} ||
= || \mathbf{r}_0 + (\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{p} -
\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{r}_0)\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{p} ||
$$

Comment: Hint:

$$
|| \mathbf{r}_0 + (\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{p} -
\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{r}_0)\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{p} ||=
|| \mathbf{r}_0- \mathbf{p} +\mathbf{v}^{\top} (\mathbf{p} -
\mathbf{r}_0)\mathbf{v}  ||
$$
so your result seems the same.

Comment: The vector you have inside the norm is exactly the negative of what they have. Since $||\mathbf{x}|| = ||\mathbf{-x}||$ they are the same.

Comment: Yes, now I see it's the same thing. Thanks.